# mobile device resolution and browser viewport size

Tags: mobile, media-queries, screen-resolution

I got galaxy nexus with resolution is 720x1280. But when I call $(window).width() it just return 360px. Are there anyway to calculate value of $(window).width() on other devices? For an example, galaxy s 480x800? I need those values for my media queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 360px){
    body{
        font-size: 62.5%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're going to like my answer.. but here goes.

Forget about width (fixed widths at least), and make your website device-agnostic. Don't base your breakpoints on popular device resolutions, instead base them on your content. Keep stretching that browser window until you get that gut feeling that says "that doesn't look right" - that's your next breakpoint.

Keep it as fluid as you can and rely on relative units - even on your media query declaration.

I suggest giving this article by Chris Armstrong a read: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/the-infinite-grid/ (although ALA appears to be temporarily offline)